# Octogon using asteriks

Tags: java

What I need is to change my first for statement to make spaces for the bottom half of the octagon.

What I get right now looks like this 
[image]

```
public class Octo {
    public static void draw(int len, String c) {
        for (int num = 1; num <= len; num++) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
    public static void Octogon(int length){
        draw(length-1, " ");
        draw(length, "*");
        draw(length-1, " ");
        System.out.println();
        for(int row =1 ;row < length ; row++) {
            draw(length -row -1, " ");
            draw(1, "*");
            draw(length+2 *row  -2 , " ");
            draw(1, "*");
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int row2 = 1 ; row2 < 3 ; row2++) {
            System.out.println("*        *");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you copy the loop, and make `row` count down from `length-1` to `1`, instead of up.

Comment: Also, don't hardcode the number of spaces in that short loop. Use the `draw` method to print the right number of spaces, so it'll work for any value of `length`.